# What is the Redis equivalent of TransactionDB's getRange?

Tags: python, redis, jedis, foundationdb

The transactionDB python api says that,

> Database.get_range(begin, end[, limit, reverse, streaming_mode])
>
> Returns all keys k such that begin <= k < end and their associated values as a 
>   list of KeyValue objects. Note the exclusion of end from the range.
>
> This read is fully synchronous.

I want something equivalent in Redis. I looked at lrange and zrange functions but don't think that they are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR there isn't a direct equivalent and scanning the entire key space is always slow(er) - you should avoid it unless your intent is getting most/all of the keys anyway.

There are two Redis commands that allow you to scan the keyspace - one is called [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan) and the [other one](http://redis.io/commands/keys) should not be mentioned nor used for anything but development. Unlike what you're after, however, these commands:
1. Do not work on ranges of keys, but rather on glob-like patterns
2. Do not return the associated value, you have to specifically read it

Generally speaking, you should refrain from practicing such read patterns unless you mean it - in most cases, you want the responses fast and cheap, so a full scan is almost always not the right way,

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'd like to ask a probably stupid question: why shouldn't the *keys* command be used in production? I have a use case where the *keys* fits quite well.

Answer (score 0):

[Sorted sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets) allow you to query by a [range](http://redis.io/commands/zrange). If you're storing say an object, you can use the sorted set to get the desired object ID's, then lookup the object information from a hash with [hget](http://redis.io/commands/hget)/[hgetall](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall).